# Path not really given path to Python

Tags: bash

The `which` command does not seem to be giving the right result:

```
[ray@localhost ~]$ unalias python
bash: unalias: python: not found
[ray@localhost ~]$ unalias which
bash: unalias: which: not found
[ray@localhost ~]$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
[ray@localhost ~]$ /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.6
[ray@localhost ~]$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
[ray@localhost ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   11 Jun 10 12:27 /usr/local/bin/python -> python2.7.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8040 Jun 10 12:21 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8040 Jun 10 12:25 /usr/local/bin/python2.7.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1674 Jun 10 12:23 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   16 Jun 10 12:23 /usr/local/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   14 Jun 10 12:23 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> python2-config
[ray@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Though not the problem here, [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) is some good reading about why not to use `which` with `bash`

Comment: I'm setting that aside for a day I can focus on it.  Looks interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `which` is fine. bash is confused.

```
hash -d python
```

Comment: Thanks!  What does -d do?

Comment: Exactly what `help hash` says it does.